# $(\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z_d)/\Bbb Z\simeq\Bbb Z_n$ then $d\mid n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, exact-sequence

I'm in the middle of proving Hatcher 2.1.14

> Determine which abelian groups $A$ fits into a short exact sequence $0\to\Bbb Z\to A\to\Bbb Z_n\to 0$ ?

I already showed that if $A = \Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z_d$ where $d\mid n$ then the the sequence is exact. Also if the given sequence is exact, then $A\simeq \Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z_d$ for some $d$. But I'm stuck proving $d\mid n$. I tried to use $(\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z_d)/\Bbb Z\simeq\Bbb Z_n$ to show $d\mid n$, but how can I use it?

Edit: Let $0\to \Bbb Z\xrightarrow{f} A\xrightarrow{g}\Bbb Z_n\to 0$ be an exact sequence. Let $f(1)=\alpha$ and $g(\beta) =1$. I claim that $\alpha,\beta$ generates $A$. Let $x\in A$. If $x\in\operatorname{Im}(f)$ then $x$ is a multiple of $\alpha$. If $x\notin\operatorname{Im}(f)$ then by exactness, $x\notin\operatorname{Ker}(g)$ so $g(x) \neq 0$ so $g(x) = tg(\beta)$ for some $t$. Hence, $x-t\beta\in\operatorname{Ker}(g)=\operatorname{Im}(f)$ so $x =t\beta+t'\alpha$. Now by the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian group, $A\simeq \Bbb Z^l\oplus\Bbb Z_{m_1}\oplus\cdots\Bbb Z_{m_n}$ such that $m_1\mid m_2\mid\cdots \mid m_n$. Since $\Bbb Z$ is embedded in $A$, $l\geq 1$ and $A$ is generated by $\alpha,\beta$, $A\simeq\Bbb Z^2$ or $\simeq\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z_d$ for some $d$. If $A\simeq\Bbb Z^2$ then $\Bbb Z^2/\Bbb Z\simeq \Bbb Z\neq\Bbb Z_n$ which is a contradiction (But from now, I think the argument is wrong).

If $A = \Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z_d$ where $d\mid n$ then define a map $f:\Bbb Z\to A$ by $t\mapsto (qt,[t])$ where $q = n/d$. And define a map $g:A\to\Bbb Z_n$ by $(x,[y])\mapsto [x-yq]$. Then this map is well defined group homomorphism. Clearly $g\circ f =0$. Let $(x,[y])\in\operatorname{Ker}(g)$ then $g(x,[y]) =[x-yq] =0$ so $x-yq = tn$ for some $t$. Hence, $x = q(td+y)$. Now $f(td+y) = (x,[y])$ which shows the exactness. The fact that $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective is easy.

Comment: "$(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_d)/\mathbb{Z}$" doesn't make sense unless you state exactly how $\mathbb{Z}$ is embedded into the direct sum; there are infinitely many subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Please also add your proof of "If $0 \to \mathbb Z \to A \to \mathbb Z_n \to 0$ is exact, then $A \cong \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z_d$ for some $d$". This could be helpful.

Comment: Arturo's comment already applies to the first sentence "...then the sequence is exact": for which maps? A sequence is more than just a bunch of groups.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg@azif00 Edit the post

Comment: Hmm, when I saw the original problem, my first thought was: OK, let's start by calculating $\operatorname{Ext}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$.  And there's an obvious free resolution of $\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$ to use in doing that calculation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you are rather loose with your notation. That's not a good thing.

---

The first part assumes $n,d\gt 0$, which you seem to be doing implicitly in your post. Below I deal with the possibility that one or both are zero.

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_d$, and let $N$ be a cyclic subgroup such that $A/N$ is finite cyclic of order $n$. Let $(x,y)$ be a generator for $N$.

Let $k=\gcd(d,n)$; then the image of $(0,1)$ has order dividing $k$, hence $(0,k)\in N$. Thus there exists $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $m(x,y) = (0,k)$, hence $(mx,my)=(0,k)$. Thus, $mx=0$ and $my\equiv k\pmod{d}$.

Since $mx=0$, then either $x=0$ or $m=0$. If $x=0$, then $(r,0)\notin N$ for all $r\neq 0$, so $A/N$ has infinite order, which is impossible. Thus, $m=0$; hence $(0,0)=(0,k)$, so $k\equiv 0\pmod{d}$. Thus, $k=\gcd(d,n)\equiv 0\pmod{d}$, so $d=\gcd(d,n)$.

---

Here's another way, which also excludes the possibility $A=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ that you mention in the comments.  The key observation is:

> If $N$ is cyclic (written additively) and $x,y\in N$ are both nontrivial, then there exist $r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$, both nonzero, such that $rx=sy$.

Suppose $n\gt 0$.  If $A=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_d$ and $N$ be as above, with $d\geq 0$ (where $\mathbb{Z}_0$ means $\mathbb{Z}$). Let $k=\gcd(d,n)$, as above. Since both $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ have images of order dividing $n$, then $(n,0)$ and $(0,k)$ are both in $N$. (Note that $\gcd(0,n)=n$, so $k\neq 0$).

Since $N$ is cyclic, if $(0,k)\neq (0,0)$, then there must exist nonzero integers $r$ and $s$ such that $r(n,0)=s(0,k)$. But this forces $r=0$, which is impossible. Thus, it must be the case that $(0,k)=(0,0)$, so $d|k$. This excludes $d=0$ (since that would force $k=0$), and also proves that $\gcd(d,n)=d$, as required.

---

What if $n=0$? Then we must have $d=0$ in your initial setting, where $N$ is assumed to be infinite cyclic. Because $\mathbb{Z}$ is free abelian, hence projective, so the surjection $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_d\to\mathbb{Z}$ splits. If the kernel is infinite cylic, that would mean that $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_d\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus N \cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore the rank of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_d$ is two, so $\mathbb{Z}_d\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and hence $d=0$. Then $d=n=0$, so $d|n$ still holds.

Comment: I also have trouble excluding the case $A\simeq \Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z$ because I realized that $\Bbb Z^2/\Bbb Z$ doesn't make sense

Comment: @love_sodam: That would be even worse: you need both $(n,0)$ and $(0,n)$ in $N$. That's impossible with a single generator.

Comment: @love_sodam: I added a single argument that handles both the rank $1$ and rank $2$ cases together.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I simply can't see why the image of $(0,1)$ has order $k$ then $(0,k)\in N$. Also, I actually don't know projective module and what do you mean by $\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z_d\to \Bbb Z$ splits?

Comment: @love_sodam: The image of $(0,1)$ has order **dividing** $k$. That means that $0=kg(0,1) = g(k(0,1))=g(0,k)$. Since the kernel is $N$ that means $(0,k)\in N$.

Comment: @love_sodam: "The map $g\colon \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_d\to \mathbb{Z}$ splits" means there exists $h\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_d$ such that $g\circ h =\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{Z}}$.  In general, if $g\colon G\to K$ is a surjective morphism and $h\colon K\to G$ is a morphism such that $gh=\mathrm{id}_K$, then $G\cong \mathrm{ker}(g)\times K$.

Comment: @love_sodam: $\mathbb{Z}$ is projective means that any surjection onto $\mathbb{Z}$ always splits. Just pick any element $x$ that maps onto $1$ and define the morphism by $1\mapsto x$.

Comment: One comment. If I'm going to use module theory, I would use splitting lemma for the case $n =0$. Since $\Bbb Z$ is free $\Bbb Z$-module, the sequence splits, i.e. $A\simeq\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @love_sodam: If you know the “splitting lemma”, why were you asking what does it mean for a map to split? In any case, that’s *exactly* what I’m doing in the final paragraph, so I do not understand your comment.

Comment: I know the concept of "splitting lemma" but I didn't know the concept of the split of the map (I didn't know it's call the "split"). Yes I thought splitting lemma first time I saw the word split but didn't know what 'projective' means so I asked to be sure.